# why am I getting multiple executions on a single event?

Tags: javascript, mootools

There is obviously a fundamental flaw in my script, although I can't see what it is.

I am trying to change an element in a list from a 'picker'.

The script runs fine when executed once but with every new execution it increments the times it runs on every event.

Easier to understand what I mean in practice here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zbdt3/1/

```
$$('.edit').each(function(el) {
    el.addEvent('click',function() {
        $$('#picker span').each(function(im) {
            im.addEvent('dblclick',function() {
                el.getParent().getElement('p').set('text',im.get('text'));
                console.log(im.get('text'));
            });
        });
    });
});

<ul>
<li><p>X</p><span class="edit">edit</span></li>
<li><p>Y</p><span class="edit">edit</span></li>
<li><p>Z</p><span class="edit">edit</span></li>
</ul>

<div id="picker">
<span>A</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>C</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you add new event listeners on `#picked span` on every click on `.edit`. You should add them indepentently.

```
var activeEl;

$$('.edit').each(function(el) {
    el.addEvent('click',function() {
        $('picker').setStyles({
            'display':'block'
        });
        activeEl = el;             
    });
});

$$('#picker span').each(function(im) {
    im.addEvent('dblclick',function() {        
        activeEl.getParent().getElement('p').set('text',im.get('text'));          
        console.log(im.get('text'));
        $('picker').setStyle('display','none');
    });
});
```

​
Here's updated sample http://jsfiddle.net/hQqh6/

Comment: We already have found the issue, but you have at least took the effort to prepare working example :) Anyway, instead of global (or not) variable I would rather use [`.store()`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:store) and [`.retrieve()`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:retrieve) element methods for storing and retrieving data. This way you could even avoid using `activeEl.getParent().getElement('p')` every time the picker event handler is being triggered, or even improve/shorten the code more.

Answer (score 2):

You first iterate through all `.edit` elements and attach event to each of them.

In the event handler for each of them, you iterate through every `#picker span` element and attach another event handler for each of them.

This way every time the event handler for `.edit` element is fired, you attach additional event handlers for `#picker span` elements and they get stacked up. When the event on `#picker span` gets triggered, all hell breaks loose...

Answer (score 0):

Because you are selecting by `$$('.edit')` and this selector will return collection (*you have `3` elements with `class="edit"`*) through which you are doing `.each(function(el) ...` and assigning for each element `el.addEvent('click',function() ...` (*click event*). In this event handler every time `.edit` event is fired you are assigning new event handlers for `#picker span`. As the result multiple events are fired and "somewhere" it fails.

**NOTE:** As *@Tadeck* mentioned, assigning event sequentially through `.each()` (*in one-by-one manner*) is not very effective. It can be done through the selector.

Comment: Actually, he is attaching the events one-by-one. Not very efficient, but this does not create the issue here.

Comment: @Tadeck, yes, didn't got the point. I've corrected my answer. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: One more thing. I believe you have made a mistake and wrote the code for jQuery. This is a Mootools question. Mootools' [`$()` function](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window:dollar) is an alias for `document.id`, which is different from [`$$()` function](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window:dollars) (which is more similar to jQuery's `$()` function). Furthermore, Mootools' elements do not have `.click()` method (http://jsfiddle.net/JBwEd/).

Comment: @Tadeck, completely mistaken. Sorry. Still sleeping, I'll remove code snippet for not being completely wrong with this answer. Will be more attentive next time.

Comment: @PaulTRawkeen: No problem. Drink some coffee ;)